# Bootstrap Modal Popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup, modal-dialog

I have a bootstrap modal popup that has bound data to the asp.net dropdown ( inside the modal ). Now I want to save the selected value into database. My problem is the selected value of the dropdown is not getting passed in the aspx.cs (code behind ) page.

Comment: is it an aspx control with runat="server"?  post some code

Comment: Can you show a little code?

Comment: yes, it is an aspx control with runat="server"

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what the problem might be because you haven't posted any code in your question so here is a complete working example of a `DropDownList` control inside a Bootstrap modal popup, hope it helps you.

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlFood.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Fruits", Value = "1" });
        ddlFood.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Vegetables", Value = "2" });
        ddlFood.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Meat", Value = "3" });
    }
}

protected void btnDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    string favFood = ddlFood.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch modal</button>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Please select your favourite food group:<br />
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFood" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList><br />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnDone" runat="server" Text="Done" OnClick="btnDone_Click" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Denis,
Thanks, your example is working. I implemented it in my code but  But my dropDrown  can pass the first item of the dropDown Items. It can not pass anyother items to the code behind page. So, Any Suggestions, please ?

Comment: You need to wrap the code which populates the DDL inside `if(!Page.IsPostBack){}` copy my example as is in a new .aspx page and test it, you will see that it works.Once you've done this tweak your code accordingly to make it work as well

Answer (score 0):

Where you bind dropdown in page load method?  write code as below in aspx.cs

```
private void Page_Load()
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // dropdown bind code
            // OR
            // call dropdown bind function eg. bindDropdown();        
        }
    }
```

There is no issue in model popup of bootstrap.

Comment: Yes, The dropdown data getting bound on page load like you showed here in your code @ Adhik