# Bootstrap Modal Popup in ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a bootstrap modal popup that has bound data to the asp.net dropdown ( inside the modal ). Now I want to save the selected value into database. My problem is the selected value of the dropdown is not getting passed in the aspx.cs (code behind ) page.

Modal

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="760" style="display: none;">                    

   <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                                &times;

                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">am/pm/fd</h4>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <h4>Please select one</h4>
                                    <table class="nav-justified">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="drpColor" runat="server" class="form-control" onclick="add()">
                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" class="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" data-dismiss="modal" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Code Behind

```
    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     // here i don't get the selected value of the dropdown .that means                   drpColor.SelectedValue = "" ; // I get "" instead of dropdowns selected value
    }
```

Comment: add your aspx code for modal..

Comment: In your code behind(in comment) you are setting the selected value to empty. 
`drpColor.SelectedValue = "";` Try to put the selected value into a label.

Comment: What did you try in your code behind. How are you trying to get the get selected value??

Comment: i set   drpColor.SelectedValue in a variable. var id =   drpColor.SelectedValue but I am getting " " as the selected value in the code behind. So, I wrote here drpColor.SelectedValue = "" @ Rick Bronger

Comment: Cant you add a `DataValueField` to your aspx dropdownlist? 

Like so:
`<asp:DropDownList ID="drpColor" runat="server" class="form-control" onclick="add()" DataValueField="ValueField"> </asp:DropDownList>`

Comment: When the modal appears , I select an item from my dropDownList and then hit the button on the modal. On button click event on the code behind page, I am not getting the selected value of the dropdown @ Manish

Comment: Sorry, Rick

The dropDown getting bound with data from Database on PageLoad Event (aspx.cs) and I removed onclick="add()" from the dropDown becuse  it did not work for me. So, My dropDown looks like "<asp:DropDownList ID="drpColor" runat="server" class="form-control">
                                                </asp:DropDownList>"

Comment: I already answered this question when you asked it yesterday and provided a complete working example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38976400/botstrap-modal-popup